# How do I pass a value from an array defined in state into a component which beholds a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am new to React and trying to write a Todo list.

As you will see in the following snippets I define an `array` of sample todos in the `App.js`.
I call the `TodoList` component in the `App.js` and hand it the `array`.
In the `TodoList` I would like to generate for the amout of elements in my list a single Todo with a dynamic value the title.
I do get the title on the page but through the `Todolist`. How can I hand that value to the single Todo, and does that even makes sense?

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        title: 'Title',
        isCompleted: false
      },
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        title: 'Title 2',
        isCompleted: false
      },
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        title: 'Title 3',
        isCompleted: false
      }
    ]
  }

    render() {
        return (
      <div className="App">
        <LayoutEntry />
        <AddTodo />
        <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
     );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**TodoList.js**

```
class TodoList extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.todos.map((todo) => (
          <div>
            <h3>{ todo.title += " Test" }</h3> 
            <Todo />
          </div>
        ));
    }
}
export default TodoList;
```

**Todo.js**

```
class Todo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <div>
        <input id="buttonDelete" type="button" value="Delete"></input>
      </div>   
      )
    }
}
export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as a prop in your map:

```react
<Todo item={todo} key={todo.id} />
```

Then in your Todo component, you can grab the data:

```react
<div>
    <div>Title: {this.props.item.title}</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Added the key as pointed out by Richard Fazzi.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm learning react too and I have this to say to you:

Every `list` must have a key, like this:

```
const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                    <Media tag="li">
                        <Media left middle>
                            <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                        </Media>
                        <Media body className="ml-5">
                            <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                            <p>{dish.description}</p>
                        </Media>
                    </Media>
                </div>
            );
        });
```

And I really think you should use a list.

The other thing I think you should do is to create a variable with the returned value from the map, then you can return that, eaxmple:

```
return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Media list>
                        { menu }
                    </Media>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I will change my array to a list. But what does the key do for me? Will it be possible that I have to identify a dynamic  renderd <div> in certain circumstances?

Comment: the `key` allows react to realise what element has changed and render JUST THAT ELEMENT in the DOM. Because React uses virtual DOM, that's why it is required.

Comment: I understand now. Should I key all elements that change?

Comment: Yes, because of the virtual DOM I explained before. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass that value to Todo you just pass it like you did with `TodoList`:
In TodoList.jsx:

```
<Todo title={todo.title} />
```

and in Todo.jsx:

```
const { title } = this.props;
<p> Title: { title } </p>
```

Or you can pass the whole object:

```
<Todo todo={todo} />
```

```
const { title } = this.props.todo;
<p> Title: { title } </p>
```